# what changes to .Net Code and the host enviroment are required to communicate with salesforce whitch is TLS 1.2 compliant?

Tags: .net, salesforce, tls1.2

My dot net services are communicating with Salesforce. Since salesforce is enabled for TLS 1.1 and higher , what changes are needed to be made in dot net side.

On Salesforce , the TLS critical updates settings are this.

[image: Salesforce Critical Update]

As you can see, there are two TLS settings options and we are going to enable both of these.

Now Salesforce is communicating with .Net Code - webservices using salesforce outbound messages. So basically what changes are required in .Net Code and the Operating host - windows server and the IIS to make the Salesforce - Dotnet Communication successfull.

What i have understood from my RnD is this (What i want to know that the steps mentioned below are enough or am i missing on something?)

a) Either change the .Net framework for the application to 4.6 or higher.

b) Use 4.5 or 4.0 and specify securityprotocol and make some reg hacks.

Are these steps enough or i have to make the windows server and IIS Server where .net services are hosted TLS compliant ?

Reference : https://success.outsystems.com/Support/Enterprise_Customers/Maintenance_and_Operations/(.NET)_Enable_SSL_Protocols_for_your_Integrations_-_TLS_1.1_and_TLS_1.2

http://blogs.perficient.com/microsoft/2016/04/tsl-1-2-and-net-support/

Answer (score 1):

Whatever library that your .net setup uses for SSL needs to be upgraded or is there is a setting that needs to be set for it to default to using TLS 1.1 or higher that needs to be set.  You may need to upgrade your version of .net on the server see the following:

http://blogs.perficient.com/microsoft/2016/04/tsl-1-2-and-net-support/

Comment: see the attached blog post but in essence yes you would probably need to upgrade your version of .net if that is an option in your case it would make the most sense to me, not sure about your setup and your current version and your dependencies.  That's all things  you would have to look into.